# Why do I receive a 403 status when I make this request?

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I'm developing a web app in django and vue js. I write a function to make a request to the api, and until now everything gone well, but in my first post request I have a problem:

Here there are:

the onsubmit function, the function that make the request, the api and the permission

```
onSubmit() {
        if (!this.questionBody) {
            this.error = 'Devi inserire un domanda!'
        } else if (this.questionBody.length > 240){
            this.error = 'La tua domanda deve contenere meno di 240 caratteri!'
        } else {
            let endpoint = 'api/questions/';
            let method = 'POST';
            apiService(endpoint, method, {content:this.questionBody})
                .then(data => 
                        this.$router.push({
                        name: 'question',
                        params: { slug: data.slug }
                    }));
        }
```

---

```
function apiService(endpoint, method, data) {
    const config = {
        method: method || 'GET',
        body: data !== undefined ? JSON.stringify(data) : null,
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': CSRF_TOKEN
        }
    };
    return fetch(endpoint, config)
           .then(data => getJson(data))
           .catch(err => err)};
```

---

```
class QuestionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Question.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
lookup_field = 'slug'
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsAuthorOrReadOnly]

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

---

```
class IsAuthorOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):

def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
        return True
    
    return request.user == obj.author
```

I receive a 403 status code when I submit the form, noticed that if I make the request using the browsable API provided by django rest framework it workd good.

Comment: Have you read [Wikiepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403)? My first guess is that `return request.user == obj.author` returns `False`.

Comment: @jabaa I also noticed this, but as I wrote, using the browsable api it works.

Comment: You could start the server in the debugger and set a breakpoint in the first line of `has_object_permission`. But you should first read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @jabaa I've put a default `return True`, in the permission class, but It still doesn't work.

Comment: What's with the debugger? Does it enter this function?

Comment: I also checked that I am authenticated and I am

Comment: @jabaa, now I try with the debugger, but the problem is not in the permission class.

Comment: But you have to find out why the server returns 403 and I'm not even sure the problem is in the posted code. Debug your code to find the problem.

Comment: If it's not in the permission class, then its most likely in the authentication classes. How did you know you are authenticated? Does `IsAuthenticated ` return true? Can you show your `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`?

Comment: @bdbd here the authentication classes `'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],`     I know that I am authenticated because in the index.html of the project I display request.user provided by the class based view.

Comment: I've discovered that the problem is the csrf_token, I paste it now but in the post requests it hasn't been send.

Comment: Great! In that case can you show us how you are getting the CSRF token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that Django accepts a request from the browser and not a request from your code... Maybe there's something missing in the http headers, something like `"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"` or something like that, yeah It is also important to check if the Django API responds to a request made from your server, some apis only accept requests that come from the server, and not requests that come from the client, in this example, the code in vuejs makes the request from the computer of the client and maybe the Django server isn't accepting it this way.
Maybe it's a CORS issue too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Please read [Should we guess an answer, with an educational purpose to help novice programmers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348494/should-we-guess-an-answer-with-an-educational-purpose-to-help-novice-programmer): _"No, we don't want people posting wild guesses as answers to unclear questions. That's why unclear questions get closed in the first place."_